# Check if object already exist

Tags: c#

Is it possible to check if an object already exists? (ex. `UserControl usercontrol1 = new UserControl()`)
Then if the `usercontrol1` does not exist in winform I will add it.

Comment: `if (usercontrol1 == null) { usercontrol1 = new UserControl(); }` or `usercontrol1 = usercontrol1 ?? new UserControl();`

Comment: I can't tell what you mean.  `usercontrol1` is a variable that refers to a newly created `UserControl` object.  You could set it to another `UserControl` object, or you could set it to `null`.  If you want to check that your newly created object _exists in winform_, well, if you haven't already added it to the form, then it doesn't.  You just created it, that's all it knows.

Comment: uhm why do you have to check it? you can just create another control anytime you want under your own conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us suppose that you have a form named as FormTest and control named as ControlTest then you can check as follows:

```
FormTest objectFormTest = new FormTest();
ControlTest objectControlTest = new ControlTest();
objectFormTest.Controls.Add(objectControlTest);   
bool isControlExist = IsControlTestContains();

public bool IsControlTestContains()
{
  bool IsControlExist = false;
  if(objectFormTest==null || objectControlTest==null)
  {
      return false;
  }
  if(objectFormTest.Controls.Contains(objectControlTest))
  {
        IsControlExist=true;
  }
  return IsControlExist;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this also. `Controls.ContainsKey()` method.

```
if (!this.Controls.ContainsKey("ControlName"))
{
    // Do Something..create new control.
}
```

Comment: This is not a good idea to use control name as control name can be changed anytime by the programmer and control name is not a constant.

Comment: ControlName is an example.